# Why session expires automatically with codeigniter ? if use ajax calling on webpage

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter, session

I am new comer with php codeigniter session. i have a issue about session expiration on my site.
         I am using ajax coll for laoding advertizing div on our site page and also add to cart feature to add multiple products on same page. but my cart added products is empty due to session getting expired after appro. 4-5 minutes.
I have done lot of study about this issue. i think my site session is expired due to colling ajax and updating session id at same time.But i am not sure for that.

**I have configured config.php file like -**

```
$config['sess_cookie_name'] = 'ci_session';
$config['sess_expiration']  = 0;
$config['sess_encrypt_cookie']= FALSE;
$config['sess_use_database']= TRUE;
$config['sess_table_name']  = 'ci_sessions';
$config['sess_match_ip']    = FALSE;
$config['sess_match_useragent']= TRUE;
$config['sess_time_to_update'] = 300;
```

I have also created table(ci_sessions).

**Please give me a solution to fix this issue.**

Thanks.

Comment: codeigniter what version?

Comment: @Charlie ,I am using codeigniter 1.7.2 .

Comment: Please Please ,Give simple solution of this issue because i very new comer with codeigniter

Comment: why dont just use newer version since you're new to CI ?

Comment: @Charlie , Thanks for suggestion . But can not change my existing version due to some working company reason.**Please Give alternate solution**

Comment: you got two answer, still no right solution ??

Comment: @Charlie , Please Explain me , how to use MY_Session.php(/application/libraries/MY_Session.php) file after creating on controller.according to your first solution

Comment: the most simple solution is replace session.php with [this one](https://raw.github.com/EllisLab/CodeIgniter/b211adee89f5fd2192051e9c0826146bd150f469/system/libraries/Session.php), and done. If you prefer to extend the session.php, I am not sure, just ask the answerer.

Comment: @Charlie , Ok sir i just trying this

Comment: dont use MY_Session.php

Comment: @Charlie , 
Fatal error: Call to undefined method CI_Input::is_ajax_request() in C:\wamp\www\mysadagi_voicetongues\system\libraries\Session.php on line 365

Answer (score 5):

There was a patch for session.php in CI last year that resolved the issue of ajax+session expire problem please the look at the following patch [LINK HERE](http://upshots.org/codeigniter/codeigniter-ajax-session-bug-fix)

Answer (score 4):

Just make sure, there is two option.

1.Replace `system\libraries\Session.php` with [this one](http://upshots.org/codeigniter/codeigniter-ajax-session-bug-fix)

2.Extend your original session.php like @undefined answer.

If you do no.1 then **dont** do no.2, and vice versa.

I have no idea more than that. good luck !.

Comment: Thank You Sir . i am satisfy completely

Comment: wich one that working?

Comment: Your First Option is Working good with adding is_ajax_request() in system\libraries\input.php file.  Thanks for response.

Answer (score 1):

This is a CI bug, sessions are destroyed when an Ajax request is sent, you can extend the CI_Session class and call the `sess_update` only when request is not Ajax.

```
class MY_Session extends CI_Session
{
    function sess_update()
    {
        // Listen to HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH
        if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) && $_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH'] !== 'XMLHttpRequest') {
            parent::sess_update();
        }
    }
}
```

In order to load the `MY_Session` class, you can add this function to your `config` file:

```
function __autoload($classname) {
    if (strpos($classname, 'CI_') !== 0) {
        $file = APPPATH . 'libraries/' . $classname . '.php';
        if (file_exists($file) && is_file($file)) {
            @include_once($file);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: would you like to help please; see comments above. thanks.